# Reference Error: document is not defined in mapbox nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mapbox

I installed @mapbox/search-js-react package for autocompletion in next js. It throws the document is not defined error.

I tried

```
{
     typeof window !== "undefined" && <PlacesSuggest />
}
```

Still not working. Could anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why do you still get this error:

Your guard is not sufficient to prevent `document is not defined`:

The reference to `document` is evaluated before the guard: `document` is evaluated from the import of `@mapbox/search-js-react` which may be imported from `PlagesSuggest`.

You could use a dynamic import inside your guard but it will be easier to use NextJS features.

Use [dynamic import with no ssr](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr):

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const PlacesSuggest = dynamic(() => import('./PlacesSuggest'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```